# Unable to Use Specialization of std::hash for Pointer-to-Member?

Tags: c++, hash, stdhash

I assume that std::hash's specialization for generic pointer types can be used for pointer-to-members, however I am unable to use it as such; instead, my compiler gives me an "incomplete type" error, which I assume means that is' not using the specialization of std::hash for pointers? What's going on here?

```
#include <functional>

struct foo{
    void bar(int a){}
};

int main(){
    std::hash<void (foo::*)(int)> hasher;
}
```

The error:

```
..\src\m.cpp:43:32: error: aggregate 'std::hash<void (foo::*)(int)> hasher' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that pointers to member are not really pointers; they just happen to have a similar name and kind of similar syntax. `std::hash` is specialized for ordinary pointers, but not for pointers to members. You could of course specialize it yourself, but if there's a way to do that that's guaranteed to be safe, I'm not seeing it; there's not much you can do with a pointer to member other than dereference it or cast it to other pointers to members.

Answer (score 1):

change the struct declaration to:

```
struct foo{
    static void bar(int a){}
};
```

Non-static member functions have a hidden parameter that corresponds to the this pointer, that's why the compiler happens.

Comment: It is critical that I take the hash of a pointer-to-member, rather than a static function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the specialization before you can use it.

```
namespace std
{
   template <>
   struct std::hash<void (foo::*)(int)>
   {
       // Implement the class.
   };
}
```

Use it.

```
int main(){
    std::hash<void (foo::*)(int)> hasher;
}
```

Comment: That "Implement the class" glosses over the hard part of the problem- it's far from clear how to compute a hash value for a pointer-to-member.

Comment: @GeoffRomer, I agree. I am not sure the OP knows how to implement the class either. I was helping to explain the compiler error and how to overcome that.

Comment: @R Sahu as far as I know, there is no well-defined way to take the hash of a pointer-to-member. I was just (incorrectly) assuming that the pointer specialization of std::hash covered them.

Comment: @Shokwav, Perhaps the answer to this SO post might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328238/how-to-hash-and-compare-a-pointer-to-member-function