# How to define a map from function pointers to strings

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to define a map from member function pointers to strings in C++.  But the the compiler complains that operator < is not defined for member function pointers.  Is there a way to do this?

Example code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
class foo;
typedef void (foo::*fooFunc)();

class foo {
public:
  foo() {
    myMap[func]="example function";
  }
  void func() {};
  std::map<fooFunc,std::string> myMap;
};
```

Resulting error message:

```
    In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_tree.h:65:0,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.2.0/map:60,
                 from grr.cpp:1:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = void (foo::*)()]':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_map.h:501:32:   required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = void (foo::*)(); _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Compare = std::less<void (foo::*)()>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<void (foo::* const)(), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = void (foo::*)()]'
grr.cpp:9:15:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: error: invalid operands of types 'void (foo::* const)()' and 'void (foo::* const)()' to binary 'operator<'
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` requires a comparison operator for its keys. By default, it uses `operator <`. Since `operator <` is not defined for *pointer-to-member* types, you are getting this error.
To fix it you'll need to define a custom comparison operator and provide it as a parameter to `std::map`. Alternatively, use a different container.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

> std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value
>   pairs with unique keys. **Keys are sorted by using the comparison
>   function Compare.** Search, removal, and insertion operations have
>   logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as red-black
>   trees

If you want options on how to write such a comparison operator, it has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328238/how-to-hash-and-compare-a-pointer-to-member-function?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I get that I need a comparison operator, but I can't figure out how to write one for member function pointers.  I would have thought there was some way to cast it to an integer type but that doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: @q.t.f. I updated the answer, how to do that has already been answered on a different question. However, this is not straightforward, and you may want to consider a different design.

Comment: Ugh.  Basically the answer is "no" there is no efficient portable way of doing it.